# Automount of external hard disk

Tags: external-hdd, automount

I have an Intenso 6002560 1TB Memory Station - an external hard disk. This hard disk gets connected via Y-USB cable. When I connect both USB-ends to my Notebook, it gets recognized by my Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS system:

```
moose@pc07:~$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 13fd:1840 Initio Corporation 
[...]
```

and

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00065e10

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       37810   303704064   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           37810       38914     8864769    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           37810       38914     8864768   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0d6ea32a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1      121601   976759008+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

But it did not get mounted:

```
moose@pc07:/dev$ mount -l
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/moose/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=moose)
```

However, I could mount it manually with

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1
```

as you can see here:

```
moose@pc07:~$ mount -l
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/moose/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=moose)
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/sdc1 type vfat (rw)
```

edit: Another command:

```
moose@pc07:~$ sudo blkid -o list
device                     fs_type    label       mount point                    UUID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1                  ext4                   /                              45eb611b-517e-425b-8057-0391726cccd5
/dev/sda5                  swap                   <swap>                         e9dc42f3-594c-4b62-874a-305eda5eed41
moose@pc07:~$ blkid -o list
device                     fs_type    label       mount point                    UUID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1                  ext4                   /                              45eb611b-517e-425b-8057-0391726cccd5
/dev/sda5                  swap                   <swap>                         e9dc42f3-594c-4b62-874a-305eda5eed41
/dev/sdc1                                         /mnt/sdc1
```

edit: another command:

```
moose@pc07:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2012-09-30 09:31 45eb611b-517e-425b-8057-0391726cccd5 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2012-09-30 09:31 e9dc42f3-594c-4b62-874a-305eda5eed41 -> ../../sda5
```

Here is a link to a [Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/202922) about this problem.

But I would like it to mount automatically. What do I have to do?

Comment: hi, this is strange, the result you show is like it was not actually mounted. If you try ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ so you list all in an other way, what is the output?

Comment: @user81022: it outputs only the two partitions of my internal hdd, see edited post.

Comment: I think since the drive is fat32, you should mount it as sdb type (not sdc). So, first sudo umount /dev/sdc1 and then re-mount it (/dev/sdb1). I wish I could help more.

Comment: `/dev/sdb1` does not exist (`mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
`). If I try to mount `/dev/sdb` it says `mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb`. By the way, `chkdisk` on a windows machine did not reveal any errors. It worked on Windows out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question but I figured this might still help someone.

I've had the same problem with this hdd. The source turned out to be the initial format of the partition. **Reformatting as NTFS** using the *Disks* (gnome-disks) tool made it behave like any other usb hdd.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much! Do you know if there is a MATE tool with which this can be done?

Comment: Awesome! Not sure what you mean by "MATE tool" – in any case, if gnome-disks isn't available, mkfs.ntfs should also do the trick on most systems.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good guide on how to mounting drives.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

You should add your drive to the /etc/fstab file which controls the mounted devices, with parameters such as

- the mounting drive,
- the mounting point
- used filesystem
- and several other options

good luck!

**EDIT:** If you modify fstab manually instead of using some interface, be careful with the lines you change. Do a backup of the file first or you could make your system to not boot properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is mounted, run sudo blkid so you see the UUID of the volume.
Then, in /etc/fstab, add:

UUID=xxx /media/xxx vfat 0 0

Comment: it seems not to have a UUID (see my edit). What do I do now? (and why isn't the device displayed when I run `blkid` with `sudo`?)